# How to make own flash debugger?

Tags: debugging, flash

Could someone explain or provide any links on some info on writing flash debugger (connecting mechanism, trace)? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like a Logging target or really a full spec debugger?

Comment: @DennisJaamann, only tracing would be enough. I'm just interested in connecting mechanism and catching trace.

Comment: DeMonster Debugger is an open source flash debugger, check the source: http://demonsterdebugger.com/

Comment: @Rob Fox, thanks! BTW, why won't you post it as an answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of readily available solutions for you

- Use FireBug for firefox with the Flashbug plugin
- Use [ThunderBolt](http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/)
- Use [Flex Console](http://code.google.com/p/flex-console/)
- Use [DemonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/)
- Use [Flash Console](http://code.google.com/p/flash-console/)

If you still want to roll your own

- For Flex, you can use the Logging API provided in the Flex framework

  Some official docs on the flex logging API:
  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f0f.html

Cheers

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually I do not really need debugger, I'm entirely satisfied with one provided by IDE. It's just my curiosity :)

Answer (score 1):

DeMonster Debugger is an open source flash debugger, check the source at: [demonsterdebugger.com](http://demonsterdebugger.com)